# relocation R_X86_64_32 against.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object, recompile with-fPIE

Tags: c, compiler-errors, coursera-api

```make
CFLAGS=-ggdb3 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=gnu99 -g

GIVEN_OBJS=deck-c4.o  eval-c4.o  future.o  input.o  main.o

MY_OBJS=cards.o deck.o eval.o

test-eval: deck.o eval.o eval-c4.o test-eval.o deck-c4.o cards.o input.o future.o
    gcc -o test-eval -ggdb3 deck.o deck-c4.o eval-c4.o eval.o test-eval.o cards.o input.o future.o
   

poker: $(GIVEN_OBJS) $(MY_OBJS)
    gcc -o poker -ggdb3  $(MY_OBJS) $(GIVEN_OBJS)
clean:
    rm -f test poker cards.o my-test-main.o *~
```

Makefile code^

`[i am trying to compile by using a command "make test-eval" but the object files show me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jofNh.png)

i tired using "-fPIE" but it does not work and when i use "-no-pie" in the makefile it works but gives me the wrong output

Comment: Please post the text inline as text, not as links to png.

Comment: What is the difference between the `$(GIVEN_OBJS)` .o files and the `$(MY_OBJS)` .o files in the Makefile? You only seem to be getting the relocation errors with the `$(GIVEN_OBJS)` .o files. Can those be recompiled?

Comment: MY_OBJS are object files that i have created and GIVEN_OBJS are the objects files my course gave me in a file

Comment: Did the course tell you how to build it, i.e. what compiler and linker options to use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "**when i use "-no-pie" in the makefile it works but gives me the wrong output**", but it sounds like you just need to use that `-no-pie` and debug your code.

Comment: When I use -no-pie and compile the course fails me tho I did not try debugging it

Comment: Grading at Fri 29 Sep 2023 05:32:08 PM UTC
Compiling your code
rm test poker cards.o my-test-main.o *~
cc -ggdb3 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=gnu99   -c -o deck.o deck.c
'make test-eval' failed.

Overall Grade: F

this is what i get when i use -no-pie in my makefile

Comment: I cannot guess what the coursework wants you to do to complete the task.

Comment: the course just wants me to make a deck of playing cards and evaluate the outcomes between 2 players i have done all the coding part and then when i compile the files all the files got compiled except the object files and it gives me that error

Comment: So "make test-eval failed" is the only error? There is something that runs "make clean" followed by "make test-eval"? What does it expect "make test-eval" to do? Why is your "test-eval" target pretty much a duplicate of your "poker" target? Why does your "clean" rule remove things that haven't been built (test and my-test-main.o) but doesn't remove things that have been built (test-eval and ${MY_OBJS))?

Comment: when i started my assignment i was given this file with Makefile already written it makes 2 programs test-eval and poker. test-eval program. It specifies the dependencies (object files) required for building test-eval and provides the command to link them into an executable. poker program. It specifies that the poker executable depends on both the given object files ($(GIVEN_OBJS)) and my object files ($(MY_OBJS)). It provides the command to link these object files into the poker executable. the 'clean' command is just used to clean up the project directory

Comment: when I run "make test-eval," it compiles and links the source files and object files required for the "test-eval" program according to the rules defined in the Makefile. The resulting executable allows me to run the "test-eval" program, which appears to be used for testing my code of evaluating poker hands.

Comment: So can you actually run the test-eval program?

Comment: yes but the error doesnt let me i dont know how to fix it